# Can I tint texture inside an actor?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

I need to tint an item in my ShopCell (it should be black at first, and after purchase it becomes normal).

```
public class ShopCell extends Group {
private final float WIDTH = 100;
private final float HEIGHT = 150;
private Label label;

public ShopCell(TextureRegion itemTxt, int price) {
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Image cellBg = new Image(Resource.cellBg);
    cellBg.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Image item = new Image(itemTxt);
    float aspectRatio = item.getWidth()/item.getHeight();
    item.setBounds(cellBg.getX() + WIDTH/2-(HEIGHT*0.3f*aspectRatio), cellBg.getY() + HEIGHT/3, HEIGHT*0.6f*aspectRatio, HEIGHT*0.6f);
    label = new Label(String.valueOf(price), new Label.LabelStyle(Resource.font, Color.YELLOW));
    label.setPosition(cellBg.getX() + WIDTH/2 - label.getWidth()/2, cellBg.getY() + HEIGHT/15);
    this.addActor(cellBg);
    this.addActor(item);
    this.addActor(label);
}
```

I've tried to make `Sprite` at first, tint it like this and add it to `Image`:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(itemTxt);
sprite.setColor(Color.BLACK);
Image item = new Image(sprite);
```

But when I do so, my texture doesn't tint.
How can I tint it and add it to the `Group`? And can I return its normal appearence then (for purchased items)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sprite` class having own color so that can be tint but when you create `Image` from that `Sprite`, only `TextureRegion` of Sprite used for construction of new Image object.

Set color of Image instead of tinted Sprite :

```
Image item = new Image(itemTxt);
item.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

You can also try fadeIn/Out Action on your object

```
image.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(2));
```